# Illegal context in name: java:app/jdbc/ActionBazaarDS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, wildfly

An EAR with the below contents:
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/application.xml
META-INF/glassfish-resources.xml
META-INF/wildfly-ds.xml
actionbazaar-chapter3-client.jar
actionbazaar-chapter3-ejb.jar
actionbazaar-chapter3-web.war

fails to deploy in WildFly 9 with the exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYNAM0030: Illegal context in name: java:app/jdbc/ActionBazaarDS"`

The file META-INF/wildfly-ds.xml configures a datasource for the application with the problematic JNDI name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema
        http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_1.xsd">
    <datasource enabled="true"
        jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/ActionBazaarDS"
        pool-name="Chapter3EmbeddedH2Pool">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:chapter3 ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

The same JNDI name works with GlassFIsh 4.1. But I am not sure what is wrong here.
Please explain what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

The `wildfly-ds.xml` file is a mechanism that exists primarily for backwards compatibility. The JNDI name is expected to be in a global namespace such as `java:jboss/jdbc/ActionBazaarDS`.

Any Java EE 7 compliant implementation now allows you to configure data sources in the standard deployment descriptors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd"
            version="7">
    <module>
        <java>actionbazaar-chapter3-client.jar</java>
    </module>
    <module>
        <ejb>actionbazaar-chapter3-ejb.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>actionbazaar-chapter3-web.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/actionbazaar</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
    <data-source>
        <name>java:app/jdbc/ActionBazaarDS</name>
        <url>jdbc:h2:mem:chapter3 ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</url>
        ... 
    </data-source>
</application>
```

This should permit you to declare the DataSource in the java:app namespace as this is implied by the examples in the specifications.